# I Want to perform performance testing using JMETER with Fix users and Time

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

My requirement in JMeter for performance testing is 
5 Minutes for 300 Users
I want to know which parameters should i pass to run this scenario

Number of Threads (users) : ?
Ramn-up Period : ?
Loop Count : ?

schedular
Scheduler Configuration
Duration :
Startup Delay :

Answer (score 1):

Essential [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration would be:

- Number of Threads: `300`
- Loops: tick "Forever" or type `-1`
- Duration (seconds): `300`

[image: JMeter Thread Group Configuration]

However it is recommended to increase (and decrease) the load **gradually** to both JMeter and application under test could adopt for increasing load. Moreover you will be able to correlate increasing load with main performance metrics like how does response time and/or throughput change as load increase, when errors start occurring, etc.

So it will be more convenient to use i.e. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) where you can easily configure workload like:

- During 1st minute users arrive
- Then 300 users hold load for 3 minutes
- Then during last minute users are being shut down

[image: JMeter Ultimate Thread Group Example]

You can install Ultimate Thread Group (as well as other Custom Thread Groups) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Ultimate Thread Group Installation]

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitri,  It helps me a lot,

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitri,  It helps me a lot,but I have the following scenarios , 1) First user will login in 5 min with 300 users and then next 20 min for 150 users for other scenarios then 5 minuts for 40 users for other scenario, How to prepare such a script and run it.